# electro-forge start reports error node-gyp reconstruction failed

Tags: gyp

```bash
admin@DESKTOP-BNTFPQK MINGW64 /d/code/cloud-pue (master)
$ npm run start
```

```
> cloud-pue@0.0.2 start
> electron-forge start

✔ Checking your system
✔ Locating application
✔ Loading configuration
✖ Preparing native dependencies: 1 / 2
  › node-gyp failed to rebuild 'D:\code\cloud-pue\node_modules\.store\ffi-napi@4.0.3\node_modules\ffi-napi'
◼ Running generateAssets hook

› Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\code\cloud-pue\node_modules\.store\node-gyp@9.4.1\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 42, in <module>
  import gyp  # noqa: E402
  ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\code\cloud-pue\node_modules\.store\node-gyp@9.4.1\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  import gyp.input
  File "D:\code\cloud-pue\node_modules\.store\node-gyp@9.4.1\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\input.py", line 19, in <module>
  from distutils.version import StrictVersion
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
  Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
      at ChildProcess.onCpExit (D:\code\cloud-pue\node_modules\.store\node-gyp@9.4.1\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:325:16)
      at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:29…

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: node-gyp failed to rebuild 'D:\code\cloud-pue\node_modules\.store\ffi-napi@4.0.3\node_modules\ffi-napi'
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\code\cloud-pue\node_modules\.store\@electron+rebuild@3.6.0\node_modules\@electron\rebuild\lib\module-type\node-gyp\node-gyp.js:118:24)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
```

I debug before packaging,Then it reported an error, how can i solve ?